# Android error on change layout in same activity

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, numberformatexception

I'm developing an android application. It is an exam app. When a user clicks an answer, the application changes the layout with `$setContentView();` in same activity.
But it gives an error for layout **Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '@2131230721' as integer**

My layout file is below, if you need I can put my project myserver. And I can paste my activity code, but it's a basic `setContentView()` only. I guess one of my id's is causing the error but i couldn't find it.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/soruNoIleriVeGeri"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.01"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/SoruLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/question_top_plain"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/OncekiSoru"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/qIPrevious"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back_button"
                android:onClick="qIPrevious"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="57dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/about_question" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/add_favourite" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/goToQuestion"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onshowQuestion"
                android:src="@drawable/show_question" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.57" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/homeButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/tab_home"
                android:onClick="goHome" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/next_button"
                android:onClick="qINextQuestion" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/question_top_plain"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/resultIconPlain"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="234dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.13"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#111" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:background="@drawable/question_top_plain" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dogruCevap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/StatikDogruCevap"
                android:layout_width="126dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/StatikDogruCevap"
                android:textStyle="@style/boldText" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.01" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dogruCevapView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textStyle="@style/rightAnswer" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cevabiniz"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cevabinizView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textStyle="@style/rightAnswer" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/StatikCevap"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/StatikCevap"
                android:textStyle="@style/boldText" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="350px"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dogruCevapAyrinti"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.60"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:minHeight="400px"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dogruCevapAyrintiView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="324dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#111" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is error codes  and myActivity sorry for Turkish variable names

```
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
    at      

       com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:320)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
    ... 41 more
        java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '@2131230721' as integer
    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:363)
    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:121)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:201)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:647)



    package com.eandroid.workingSet;

 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
 import org.w3c.dom.Document;
 import org.w3c.dom.Element;
 import org.w3c.dom.Node;
 import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
 import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.TabActivity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.res.Configuration;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.LinearLayout;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

     import com.eandroid.entity.Question;

    public class QuestionInterfaceActivity extends Activity {
LinearLayout layoutForA;
LinearLayout layoutForB;
LinearLayout layoutForC;
LinearLayout layoutForD;
LinearLayout layoutForE;
LinearLayout choiceATotalPlain;
LinearLayout choiceBTotalPlain;
LinearLayout choiceCTotalPlain;
LinearLayout choiceDTotalPlain;
LinearLayout choiceETotalPlain;
LinearLayout allTotalPlain;
List<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
Node node = null;
NodeList nodeList = null;
NodeList nodeListForTestInfo = null;
InputStream is = null;

private TextView choiceA;
private TextView choiceB;
private TextView choiceC;
private TextView choiceD;
private TextView choiceE;
private TextView questionText;
private TextView soruIdText;
private TextView soruIdEv;
private TextView soruBilgileriView;
private TextView cevabinizView;
private TextView dogruCevapView;
private TextView dogruCevapAyrintiView;
private TextView resultView;
private int currentQuestionIndex;
Question currentQuestion = null;
private String testName = null;
HttpClient httpclient;
HttpPost httppost;
ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
HttpResponse response;
InputStream contentStream;
private String rightAnswers = "";
private String userAnswers = "";
private String resultOfAnswers = "";
private String userId = "1";
private static String testRelationId;
private LinearLayout resultIconPlain;

private static String willPostUrl = 
     "http://balabanhafriyat.com/SchoolProjectWebSide/postFromPhone/SendDataFromPhone";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Toast.makeText(QuestionInterfaceActivity.this, "Hoşgeldin  Hacı",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    settleOrientation();
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        testName = extras.getString("testName");
    }
    try {
        is = getAssets().open(testName);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(is));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("question");
        nodeListForTestInfo = doc.getElementsByTagName("testInfo");
        Node testNode = nodeListForTestInfo.item(0);
        testRelationId = parseItToStringByName(testNode, "testRelationId");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    currentQuestionIndex = 1;
    showQuestion();
}

public void settleOrientation() {
    int setLayout = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    switch (setLayout) {
    case 1:
        setContentView(R.layout.buttontry);
        loadDesign();
        break;
    case 2:
        setContentView(R.layout.buttontry);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

public void callEvaluationActivity(int optionToSeeQuestion,
        String userAnswer) {

    setContentView(R.layout.evaluation_screen);


    // resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultView);

    cevabinizView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cevabiniz);
    dogruCevapView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rightAnswer);

    dogruCevapAyrintiView = (TextView) 
            findViewById(R.id.dogruCevapAyrintiView);
    // soruBilgileriView.setText(currentQuestion.getShortInfo());

    dogruCevapAyrintiView.setText(currentQuestion.getRightAnswerDetail());
    dogruCevapView.setText(currentQuestion.getRightAnswer());
    if (optionToSeeQuestion == 2) {
        cevabinizView.setText(userAnswer);
        if (currentQuestion.getRightAnswer().equals(userAnswer)) {
            resultView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            resultView.setText("Doğru Cevap");
            resultOfAnswers = resultOfAnswers + "1$";
        } else {
            resultView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            resultView.setText("Cevap Yanlış !!! ");
            resultOfAnswers = resultOfAnswers + "0$";
        }
        userAnswers = userAnswers + userAnswer + "$";
        rightAnswers = rightAnswers + currentQuestion.getRightAnswer()
                + "$";
    }
}



public void loadDesign() {
    allTotalPlain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.allTotalPlain);
    allTotalPlain.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow_button);
    choiceATotalPlain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.choiceTotalPlain);
    choiceBTotalPlain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.choiceBTotalPlain);
    choiceCTotalPlain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.choiceCTotalPlain);
    choiceDTotalPlain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.choiceDTotalPlain);
    choiceETotalPlain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.choiceETotalPlain);
    layoutForA = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.abuttonLayout);
    layoutForB = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bButtonLayout);
    layoutForC = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cButtonLayout);
    layoutForD = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dButtonLayout);
    layoutForE = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ebuttonLayout);
    createButton("A");
    createButton("B");
    createButton("C");
    createButton("D");
    createButton("E");
}

private void showQuestion() {
    questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.soruTextView);
    choiceA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choiceA);
    choiceB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choiceB);
    choiceC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choiceC);
    choiceD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choiceD);
    choiceE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choiceE);
    currentQuestion = setQuestionFieldById(currentQuestionIndex);
    questionText.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestionText());

    choiceA.setText(currentQuestion.getChoiceA());
    choiceB.setText(currentQuestion.getChoiceB());
    choiceC.setText(currentQuestion.getChoiceC());
    choiceD.setText(currentQuestion.getChoiceD());
    choiceE.setText(currentQuestion.getChoiceE());
    /*
     * consumerAnswer .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new
     * OnCheckedChangeListener() { public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup
     * group, int checkedId) { if (choiceA.getId() == checkedId) {
     * approveAnswer(2, "A"); } if (choiceB.getId() == checkedId) {
     * 
     * approveAnswer(2, "B"); } if (choiceC.getId() == checkedId) {
     * 
     * approveAnswer(2, "C"); } if (choiceD.getId() == checkedId) {
     * 
     * approveAnswer(2, "D"); } if (choiceE.getId() == checkedId) {
     * 
     * approveAnswer(2, "E"); } } });
     */
}

private void approveAnswer(int optionToSeeQuestion, final String userChoice) {
    callEvaluationActivity(optionToSeeQuestion, userChoice);
}

// Eger optionToSeeQuestion 1 ise kullanıcının cevap karsılastırılması
// yapılmamalı 2 ise yapılmalı

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 999) {
        if (data.hasExtra("action")) {
            String aim = data.getExtras().getString("aim");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ne yapmak istiyorsunuz" + aim,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public void qINextQuestion(View view) {

    if (currentQuestionIndex == nodeList.getLength() - 1) {
        Toast.makeText(QuestionInterfaceActivity.this, "Son Sorudasınız",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        currentQuestionIndex++;
        settleOrientation();
        showQuestion();
    }
}

public void qIPrevious(View view) {
    if (currentQuestionIndex == 1) {
        Toast.makeText(QuestionInterfaceActivity.this, "İlk Sorudasınız",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        currentQuestionIndex--;
        settleOrientation();
        showQuestion();
    }
}

public Question setQuestionFieldById(int questionId) {
    Question q = new Question();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        node = nodeList.item(i);

        int idFromXml = Integer.parseInt(parseItToStringByName(node,
                "questionNumber"));
        if (questionId == idFromXml) {
            q.setQuestionId(questionId);
            q.setChoiceA(parseItToStringByName(node, "choiceA"));
            q.setChoiceB(parseItToStringByName(node, "choiceB"));
            q.setChoiceC(parseItToStringByName(node, "choiceC"));
            q.setChoiceD(parseItToStringByName(node, "choiceD"));
            q.setChoiceE(parseItToStringByName(node, "choiceE"));
            q.setQuestionText(parseItToStringByName(node, 
                            "questionText"));
            q.setRightAnswer(parseItToStringByName(node,  
                            "rightAnswer"));
            q.setRightAnswerDetail(parseItToStringByName(node,
                    "answerDetail"));

        }

    }
    return q;
}

public String parseItToStringByName(Node node, String nodeName) {
    Element mainELement = (Element) node;
    NodeList questionList = mainELement.getElementsByTagName(nodeName);
    Element questionElement = (Element) questionList.item(0);
    NodeList question = questionElement.getChildNodes();
    String result = question.item(0).getNodeValue().replaceAll("\n", "")
            .replaceAll("\t", "");
    result.trim();
    return result;
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.landscapequestion);
        showQuestion();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        setContentView(R.layout.buttontry);
        showQuestion();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    beforeQuitProcess();
    super.onBackPressed();

}

public void beforeQuitProcess() {
    postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("testId", testRelationId));
    postParameters
            .add(new BasicNameValuePair("rightAnswers", rightAnswers));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userAnswers", userAnswers));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userAnswerAndResult",
            resultOfAnswers));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", userId));
    PostDataToServer postDataToServer = new PostDataToServer();
    HttpResponse response = postDataToServer.postData(willPostUrl,
            postParameters);
    contentStream = postDataToServer.parseHttpResponseToStream(response);
    String responseFromServer = postDataToServer
            .convertStreamToString(contentStream);
    if (responseFromServer != null) {
        Toast.makeText(QuestionInterfaceActivity.this, "Kayıt Edildi",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}



@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Toast.makeText(QuestionInterfaceActivity.this, "Çıktı Hacı",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
    // killed and restarted.
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("MyBoolean", true);
    savedInstanceState.putDouble("myDouble", 1.9);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("MyInt", 1);
    savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", "Welcome back to Android");
    // etc.
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    finish();

}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Toast.makeText(QuestionInterfaceActivity.this, "Hoşgeldin  Hacı",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
    boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MyBoolean");
    double myDouble = savedInstanceState.getDouble("myDouble");
    int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyInt");
    String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString");

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
}

public void onshowAnswer(View v) {
    callEvaluationActivity(1, "A");
}

public void onshowQuestion(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.buttontry);
    loadDesign();
    showQuestion();

}

public void goHome(View view) {
    beforeQuitProcess();
    Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionInterfaceActivity.this,
            LoginEvaluation.class);
    intent.putExtra("userId", userId);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void createButton(final String text) {
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selector);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clickMeMyFriend(view, text);
        }
    });
    button.setText(text);
    if (text.equals("A")) {
        layoutForA.addView(button);
    }
    if (text.equals("B")) {
        layoutForB.addView(button);
    }
    if (text.equals("C")) {
        layoutForC.addView(button);
    }
    if (text.equals("D")) {
        layoutForD.addView(button);
    }
    if (text.equals("E")) {
        layoutForE.addView(button);
    }
}

private void clickMeMyFriend(View view, String chooice) {
    if (chooice.equals("A")) {
        approveAnswer(2, "A");
    }
    if (chooice.equals("B")) {
        approveAnswer(2, "B");
    }
    if (chooice.equals("C")) {
        approveAnswer(2, "C");
    }
    if (chooice.equals("D")) {
        approveAnswer(2, "D");
    }
    if (chooice.equals("E")) {
        approveAnswer(2, "E");
    }

}

public void onTotalAClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.choiceTotalPlain:
        choiceATotalPlain.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_button);
        approveAnswer(2, "A");
        break;
    case R.id.choiceBTotalPlain:
        choiceBTotalPlain.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_button);
        approveAnswer(2, "B");
        break;
    case R.id.choiceCTotalPlain:
        approveAnswer(2, "C");
        choiceCTotalPlain.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_button);
        break;
    case R.id.choiceDTotalPlain:
        approveAnswer(2, "D");
        choiceDTotalPlain.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_button);
        break;
    case R.id.choiceETotalPlain:
        approveAnswer(2, "E");
        choiceETotalPlain.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_button);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}

    }
```

Thanks for all help

Comment: Your layout is ***incredibly*** inefficient and cluttered. You should ***not*** be wrapping every view in a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: What's in style/boldText and style/rightAnswer?

Comment: @SmartLemon  under res file there is a style file and an item style with rightAnswer name

Comment: **I will give a link  for my project please just download and give me sugestions .I had recode layout two times .

Comment: You should be performing your HTTP requests on a separate Thread (or AsyncTask), so as not to block the UI thread. Performing these requests on a separate thread is **very, very important** because not only will it potentially block the UI, but some of the newer ICS devices won't even run your app if they recognize that you are performing a network connection on the UI thread. Read this for more info: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you this, but there is just so much that is wrong with your `Activity` code. I would be very surprised if your app worked even if you managed to fix the `NumberFormatException` bug. You should not be manually killing processes (the `Activity` lifecycle does this for you). You should not be calling `finish()` or performing `Toast` messages in `onSaveInstanceState`. You should also be starting new activities instead of swapping different layouts in-and-out of the current activity. I strongly recommend that you start over (after taking a closer look at the activity lifecycle

Comment: documentation). The good news is that a lot of the stuff that is wrong with your code is stuff that Android does for you. If you take a good look at the documentation (or a good tutorial that builds an app w/ similar functionality), your life will be **much** easier and your app will be much more reliable as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks too much for your effort Barak , Alex Lockwood and  the others too i recode my xml layout upon your advices nothing changed but i could seen an error cant be realize before due to my unnecassary LinearLayout block .Whatever the error is :there is a statement in my layout

```
android:textStyle="@style/boldText"
```

in this statement the value can be only bold or normal etc .this statement should be like

```
style="@style/choiceStyle"
```

thanks for your help .I decided not to work after 00:00

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Comment: @AndrewKozak   "It says You can accept your own answer in 1 minute "
Funny becouse when i try just i find my error and write  this  it had said the starter can accept their own answer after 2 days .Anyway Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you are trying to use `setContentView` more than once in an activity?

From everything I have read, that won't work.

If you want to change your UI without switching activities you need to use fragments, or put all of the Views you want into your one layout and hide/show only the relevant ones for each portion of your activity with `setVisibility()`.

Comment: thanks but when you switch landscape or portrait screen option you can change layouts in same activty it shouldnt give any error

Comment: Barak I m trying setVisibility()  i will inform you about the result

Comment: An activity is a "single, focused component the user can do", the key words being "single" and "focused". Thus, it is hard to imagine a scenario in which you want to be swapping in and out entire layouts within an activity. Of course modifications are OK, but you should re-think your strategy if your layout modifications are becoming way too radical/complex. As Barak mentioned, Fragments are one way to achieve this, but I wouldn't suggest you dive into learning about them until you are more familiar with how Activitys work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting a `NumberFormatException` is because `@2131230721` is not an integer. Here's what you should do:

1. **Re-do your entire XML layout.** I am not kidding... the layout you have posted is an absolute disaster. Sorry if that's mean, but I can't let you go on thinking this is the correct way to make your layouts :).

   From what I can tell, you are wrapping every single view in a `LinearLayout` to achieve some sort of margin/padding effect. This is what the `android:margin` and `android:padding` attributes are for. Don't over-complicate things with weird `android:layout_weight` values, as this will make your app run slower when your layout gets inflated. If you ever find that your XML has more than 3 or 4 `LinearLayout`s you should take a step back and see if you are missing an easier, more efficient solution. It is frowned upon to have nested `LinearLayout`s too, as it is expensive to inflate these at runtime and will drain your battery as a result.
2. Do a <kbd>Project</kbd> --> <kbd>Clean</kbd> and restart eclipse.
3. **Post more information**. For example, your *entire* logcat output would be nice (not just one line). Posting your code is almost *always* a good idea too. It is very difficult to understand the problem from the tiny amount of information you have provided. Remember that it is beneficial to you to provide as much information as you can because the more information we have, the more likely it is that we can help answer your question. You should also provide us with line numbers and/or indicate on which lines the errors occur.

Oh yeah, and welcome to StackOverflow... :P

Comment: A pedantic point perhaps, but... nested linearlayouts are not frowned upon, nested linear layouts with the `layout_weight` attribute are frowned upon because the cause an exponential increase in processing due to having to measure and re-measure (and re-measure) the screen.

Comment: I recode the layout but i had used more Linearlayout  to add button or any element to layouts dynamically .I will try to reduce them but is there any error id define ? Thanks too much

Comment: I cleaned builded  recoded it many times :) it s so humilating for me asking a unnecessary questions so i look for all basic errors

Comment: @Barak, Sorry I should have been more clear. *Totally unnecessary* `LinearLayout`s are frowned upon. Would you agree with that? :P

Comment: @Barak, My answer was getting too technical as it was, so I was kind of trying to put it in terms the OP would understand more easily. But you are absolutely correct.

Comment: @malcomx, Keep your code up to date and I can try and help you out. It doesn't look like your XML layout or Activity code have changed much... is this the code you currently are working with?

Comment: @AlexLockwood Thanks too much for your effort Barak and the others too 
i recode my xml layout upon your advices nothing changed but i could seen an error cant be realize before due to my unnecassary LinearLayout block .Whatever the error is  there is a statement in my layout   $android:textStyle="@style/boldText"     
in this statement the value can be only bold or normal etc .this statement should be like  $style="@style/choiceStyle"  thanks for your  help .I decided not to work after 00:00 but now the time is 00:05 in Turkey

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Did you solve the problem? If not, you'll need to re-update your code and clarify the problem in your original post. It's too difficult to keep track of the changes you've made to your code from the short stackoverflow comments :).

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the weights are causing the problems? I've never used weights as decimals before, I thought they had to be real numbers, I mean like 1 or 2 etc. Floor numbers. Just a thought

From what I can see its something to do with a number and a text view, this could either be the text views color, weight, ID or style.

What's in style/boldText and style/rightAnswer?

Comment: Actually this codes works before and activity's first layout have weight attributes and values same as .I will post my project please look at it and evaluate

Answer (score -1):

You layout file does Start with a `LinearLayout` and defines a `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`, but you end up with a closing `<ScrollView>` Tag? Is there anything missing? Plus, javaCode would be great!

By the way: did u try to "clean" you project in eclipse, using Project->Clean?
This resets the R file and often helps!

Comment: @Thomas K Yep no problem on my xml at least about syntax .
stackoverflow didnt persuade to write the blocks you mentioned but thanks